# chose rows based on condition from column

Tags: r, select, rows

I am trying to do the following

```
#generate sample data
loc<-rep("Bak",3)
year<-rep(2005,3)
sea<-c("aut","sum","win")
area<-c(170,126,664)
prod<-c(154,170,932)
yld<-c(0.9,1.35,1/41)
dat<-data.frame(loc,year,sea,area,prod,yld)
```

I want to select that row where `dat$area` is maximum. This implies the third row should be selected since

```
max(dat$area)
[1] 664
```

However, I am not sure how to index this. I tried the following

```
dat[,max(dat$area)]
```

But this gives me an error. Could anyone explain me how to work this out.

Thanks

Comment: `max` doesn't give a location. Use `which.max` instead. And you've placed the condition in the wrong place. Try `dat[which.max(dat$area), ]`. Or you could do `dat[dat$area == max(dat$area), ]`. Depends if you want *all* the rows or the first one which match the condition. You could also pick up the last value out of the ordered data using `tail(dat[order(dat$area), ], 1)`

Comment: Thank you. This is very informative.

Comment: Or `dat[order(-dat$area), ][1, ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bunch of ways, here's one:

```
dat[dat$area==max(dat$area),]
```

Comment: This does it. Thanks. I will accept this answer soon

Answer (score 0):

Base R:

```
dat[dat$area == max(dat$area), ]
```

Dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
filter(dat, area == max(area))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 x<-max(dat$area) ; assign max value to a variable "x"
 subset(dat ,dat$area==x)
  loc year sea area prod        yld
3 Bak 2005 win  664  932 0.02439024
```